# Phone shuts down at about 30% battery. When booted back up, it's at 1%

Tags: battery

I'm having weird problems with my phone. I'll be using it normally, but at some point during my day, my phone is gonna shut down by itself. When I open it back up, the battery is at 1%, when not even 5 minutes before I had at least 30%. It even happenend when the battery was at 50%.

What could be my problem? Why does my battery seem to crash so quickly?

Comment: This is usually an indication of a defective or worn out battery. Can you update your question with your specific device make, model, and Android version?

Answer (score 0):

Charge your device to a certain limit, say 60% or 50%. Then, switch off the device, and again switch it on. If you find the battery has drained, switch off your phone and remove the battery, and put it into another phone. Switch that phone on. Now:

1. If the new phone shows that the battery has near about the same charge, then the following can happen:

   - Your previous phone pin that connects the battery and the phone, is defective.
   - Your previous phone microchip is sensing wrong charge.
   - Your previous phone software has a problem.

   In any of the above cases, take your phone to an authorised service centre and explain the problem.
2. The other phone shows that the battery has drained charge.

   Recharge the battery in that new phone itself. Switch it off, and switch it on.

   - If new the phone still shows that the battery has degraded similarly, then your battery is faulty. Replace the battery.
   - If new the phone shows that the battery holds charge this time, it can  be undoubtedly said that your previous phone is faulty due to the reasons previously stated. Take your phone to a service centre.

Hope this helps you. Please let us know if the problem has been sorted out.